I am creating a chess game in Unity 2D and having an issue with the moveplates. Cannot seem to get them into proper position and alignment
I started with doing everything right from the start, all functionalities are working but the positiong of the MovePlates that are supposed to highlight the possible moves are not aligning properly.
I have tried everything from code altering, Transform values trial and error, colliders and raycasting the list goes on. I even asked AI platforms multiple times but none of the solutions work.
Now I need an expert to help me solve the problem.
Transform properties for each element:
Position of chessboard: x = 8.8,  y = 8.7, z = 8.7
Scale of chessboard: x = 11.5 , y = 11.5, z = 0
Position of chesspiece: x = -3.87, y = -2.59,  z=0
Scale of chesspiece: x = 6 ,y = 6,  z = -1
Position of moveplate:  x = 0, y = 0, z = 0
Scale of moveplate:  x = 1.4375,  y = 1.4375
The green and black dots represent the next possible move of the chesspiece
I need to the green dots to appear in the cells and in proportion.
Code for the first file Game.cs :
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject ChessPiece;

    // position for each piece
    private GameObject[,] positions = new GameObject[8, 8];
    private GameObject[] playerBlack = new GameObject[16];
    private GameObject[] playerPink = new GameObject[16];

    private string currentPlayer = "pink";

    void Start()
    {

        
        playerPink = new GameObject[]
        {
             Create("pink_rook", 0, 0),
             Create("pink_knight", 1, 0),
             Create("pink_bishop", 2, 0),
             Create("pink_queen", 3, 0),
             Create("pink_king", 4, 0),
             Create("pink_bishop", 5, 0),
             Create("pink_knight", 6, 0),
             Create("pink_rook", 7, 0),
             Create("pink_pawn", 0, 1),
             Create("pink_pawn", 1, 1),
             Create("pink_pawn", 2, 1),
             Create("pink_pawn", 3, 1),
             Create("pink_pawn", 4, 1),
             Create("pink_pawn", 5, 1),
             Create("pink_pawn", 6, 1),  
             Create("pink_pawn", 7, 1),
        };

       
        playerBlack = new GameObject[]
        {
             Create("black_rook", 0, 7),
             Create("black_knight", 1, 7),
             Create("black_bishop", 2, 7),
             Create("black_queen", 3, 7),
             Create("black_king", 4, 7),
             Create("black_bishop", 5, 7),
             Create("black_knight", 6, 7),
             Create("black_rook", 7, 7),
             Create("black_pawn", 0, 6),
             Create("black_pawn", 1, 6),
             Create("black_pawn", 2, 6),
             Create("black_pawn", 3, 6),
             Create("black_pawn", 4, 6),
             Create("black_pawn", 5, 6),
             Create("black_pawn", 6, 6),
             Create("black_pawn", 7, 6),
        };

        // Position pieces on the board
        for (int i = 0; i < playerBlack.Length; i++)
        {
            SetPosition(playerBlack[i]);
            SetPosition(playerPink[i]);
        }
    }
public GameObject Create(string name, int x, int y)
    {
        GameObject obj = Instantiate(ChessPiece, new Vector3(0, 0, -1), Quaternion.identity);

        // Adjust chess piece size
        obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(12f, 12f, 12f); // Scale down or up depending on how big you want them

        Chessman cm = obj.GetComponent<Chessman>();
        cm.name = name;
        cm.SetXBoard(x);
        cm.SetYBoard(y);
        cm.Activate();

        // Adjust the chess piece's position on the board (to prevent overlap)
        obj.transform.position = new Vector3(x * 2.5f, y * 2.5f, -1);  // Adjust the spacing between pieces

        return obj;
    }

    public void SetPosition(GameObject obj)
    {
        Chessman cm = obj.GetComponent<Chessman>();
        positions[cm.GetXBoard(), cm.GetYBoard()] = obj;
    }

    public void SetPositionEmpty(int x, int y)
    {
        positions[x, y] = null;
    }

    public GameObject GetPosition (int x, int y) 
    {
        return positions[x, y];
    }

    public bool PositionOnBoard(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= positions.GetLength(0) || y >= positions.GetLength(1)) return false;
        return true;
    }
}

type here

Second file, Chessman.cs:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chessman : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject controller;
    public GameObject MovePlatePrefab;

    private int xBoard = -1;
    private int yBoard = -1;
    private string player;

    public Sprite black_queen, black_knight, black_bishop, black_king, black_rook, black_pawn;
    public Sprite pink_queen, pink_knight, pink_bishop, pink_king, pink_rook, pink_pawn;

    public void Activate()
    {
        controller = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController");
        if (!controller)
        {
            Debug.LogError("GameController not found! Ensure there is a GameObject tagged as 'GameController'.");
        }

        SetCoords();

        SpriteRenderer sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        switch (this.name)
        {
            case "black_queen": sr.sprite = black_queen; player = "black"; break;
            case "black_knight": sr.sprite = black_knight; player = "black"; break;
            case "black_bishop": sr.sprite = black_bishop; player = "black"; break;
            case "black_king": sr.sprite = black_king; player = "black"; break;
            case "black_rook": sr.sprite = black_rook; player = "black"; break;
            case "black_pawn": sr.sprite = black_pawn; player = "black"; break;
            case "pink_queen": sr.sprite = pink_queen; player = "pink"; break;
            case "pink_knight": sr.sprite = pink_knight; player = "pink"; break;
            case "pink_bishop": sr.sprite = pink_bishop; player = "pink"; break;
            case "pink_king": sr.sprite = pink_king; player = "pink"; break;
            case "pink_rook": sr.sprite = pink_rook; player = "pink"; break;
            case "pink_pawn": sr.sprite = pink_pawn; player = "pink"; break;
        }
    }

    public void SetCoords()
    {
        this.transform.position = new Vector3(xBoard * 0.66f, yBoard * 0.66f, -2.0f);
    }

    public int GetXBoard() => xBoard;
    public int GetYBoard() => yBoard;
    public void SetXBoard(int x) => xBoard = x;
    public void SetYBoard(int y) => yBoard = y;

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        DestroyMovePlates();
        InitiateMovePlates();
        Debug.Log("Chess piece clicked");
    }

    public void DestroyMovePlates()
    {
        foreach (GameObject mp in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MovePlate"))
        {
            Destroy(mp);
        }
    }

    public void InitiateMovePlates()
    {
        switch (this.name)
        {
            case "black_queen":
            case "pink_queen":
                LineMovePlate(1, 0); LineMovePlate(0, 1); LineMovePlate(1, 1);
                LineMovePlate(-1, 0); LineMovePlate(0, -1); LineMovePlate(-1, -1);
                LineMovePlate(-1, 1); LineMovePlate(1, -1);
                break;

            case "black_knight":
            case "pink_knight": LMovePlate(); break;

            case "black_bishop":
            case "pink_bishop": LineMovePlate(1, 1); LineMovePlate(1, -1); LineMovePlate(-1, 1); LineMovePlate(-1, -1); break;

            case "black_king":
            case "pink_king": SurroundMovePlate(); break;

            case "black_rook":
            case "pink_rook": LineMovePlate(1, 0); LineMovePlate(0, 1); LineMovePlate(-1, 0); LineMovePlate(0, -1); break;

            case "black_pawn": PawnMovePlate(xBoard, yBoard - 1); break;
            case "pink_pawn": PawnMovePlate(xBoard, yBoard + 1); break;
        }
    }

    public void LineMovePlate(int xIncrement, int yIncrement)
    {
        Game sc = controller.GetComponent<Game>();
        int x = xBoard + xIncrement;
        int y = yBoard + yIncrement;

        while (sc.PositionOnBoard(x, y) && sc.GetPosition(x, y) == null)
        {
            MovePlateSpawn(x, y);
            x += xIncrement;
            y += yIncrement;
        }

        if (sc.PositionOnBoard(x, y) && sc.GetPosition(x, y).GetComponent<Chessman>().player != player)
        {
            MovePlateAttackSpawn(x, y);
        }
    }

    public void LMovePlate()
    {
        PointMovePlate(xBoard + 1, yBoard + 2);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard - 1, yBoard + 2);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard + 2, yBoard + 1);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard + 2, yBoard - 1);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard + 1, yBoard - 2);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard - 1, yBoard - 2);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard - 2, yBoard + 1);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard - 2, yBoard - 1);
    }

    public void SurroundMovePlate()
    {
        PointMovePlate(xBoard, yBoard + 1); PointMovePlate(xBoard, yBoard - 1);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard - 1, yBoard - 1); PointMovePlate(xBoard - 1, yBoard);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard - 1, yBoard + 1); PointMovePlate(xBoard + 1, yBoard - 1);
        PointMovePlate(xBoard + 1, yBoard); PointMovePlate(xBoard + 1, yBoard + 1);
    }

    public void PointMovePlate(int x, int y)
    {
        Game sc = controller.GetComponent<Game>();
        if (sc.PositionOnBoard(x, y))
        {
            GameObject cp = sc.GetPosition(x, y);
            if (cp == null) MovePlateSpawn(x, y);
            else if (cp.GetComponent<Chessman>().player != player) MovePlateAttackSpawn(x, y);
        }
    }

    public void PawnMovePlate(int x, int y)
    {
        Game sc = controller.GetComponent<Game>();
        if (sc.PositionOnBoard(x, y) && sc.GetPosition(x, y) == null)
            MovePlateSpawn(x, y);

        if (sc.PositionOnBoard(x + 1, y) && sc.GetPosition(x + 1, y)?.GetComponent<Chessman>().player != player)
            MovePlateAttackSpawn(x + 1, y);

        if (sc.PositionOnBoard(x - 1, y) && sc.GetPosition(x - 1, y)?.GetComponent<Chessman>().player != player)
            MovePlateAttackSpawn(x - 1, y);
    }

    public void MovePlateSpawn(int matrixX, int matrixY, bool isAttack = false)
    {
        float cellSize = 1.4375f; // Cell width and height
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(
            matrixX * cellSize,       // X position
            matrixY * cellSize,       // Y position
            -2.0f                     // Z position (ensure it is in front of the chessboard)
        );

        GameObject mp = Instantiate(MovePlatePrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
       
        mp.tag = "MovePlate"; // Ensure the tag is set for MovePlate

        MovePlate mpScript = mp.GetComponent<MovePlate>();
        if (mpScript != null)
        {
            mpScript.SetReference(gameObject);
            mpScript.SetCoords(matrixX, matrixY);
            mpScript.attack = isAttack;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("MovePlate script is missing from the prefab.");
        }
    }
    public void MovePlateAttackSpawn(int matrixX, int matrixY)
    {
        MovePlateSpawn(matrixX, matrixY, true);
    }

    private Vector3 CalculatePosition(int matrixX, int matrixY)
    {
        float cellSize = 1.4375f; // Size of one cell
        float boardOffsetX = 8.8f; // Center of the chessboard (x position)
        float boardOffsetY = 8.7f; // Center of the chessboard (y position)

        return new Vector3(boardOffsetX + (matrixX - 0.5f) * cellSize,
                            boardOffsetY + (matrixY - 0.5f) * cellSize,
                            0); // Depth for 2D
    }

}
`



Third file, MovePlate.cs:


`using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject controller;  // GameController reference
    private GameObject reference = null;   // Chess piece reference

    // Board positions
    private int matrixX;
    private int matrixY;

    // false = movement, true = attacking
    public bool attack = false;

    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    void Start()
    {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if (attack)
        {
            if (spriteRenderer != null)
            {
                spriteRenderer.color = new Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Red color for attack
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("SpriteRenderer component is missing.");
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetCoords(int matrixX, int matrixY)
    {
        this.matrixX = matrixX;
        this.matrixY = matrixY;
        // Update position to match board coordinates
        transform.position = new Vector3(matrixX * 0.66f - 2.3f, matrixY * 0.66f - 2.3f, -3.0f);
    }

    public void SetReference(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        this.reference = gameObject;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (reference != null)
        {
            Chessman piece = reference.GetComponent<Chessman>();
            if (piece != null)
            {
                piece.SetXBoard(matrixX);
                piece.SetYBoard(matrixY);
                piece.SetCoords(); // Update the position on the board
            }
            // Destroy all move plates after moving
            DestroyMovePlates();
        }
    }

    private void DestroyMovePlates()
    {
        foreach (GameObject mp in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MovePlate"))
        {
            Destroy(mp);
        }
    }
}

I have tried all methods to alter the position and scale, be it code, unity transform values, re-coding, and changing values and implementations there, colliders, raycasters, layering, and Chatgpt and Gemini.
All of those have been able to get me only this far and no further.
I expected it to get in line with every number i changed but nothing has worked.

you sure? obj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(12f, 12f, 12f);  suggests the pieces are 12x not 6x, you also apply obj.transform.position = new Vector3(x * 2.5f, y * 2.5f, -1); to get its correct position - when you dont seem to do with the positioning of the points - but why not use a tilemap?

I think you have a fundamental design problem: it's not "object oriented"; there is no mental model. There is no "board" per se; that has "squares" that you can access via "chess notation"; or "outline". Each piece should be an object that can answer questions like: can I capture / move; etc.

I am relatively new to the concept of Unity and coding and so I created this with the help of a YouTube series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PnJceSI2gcU&list=PLXV-vjyZiT4b7WGjgiqMy422AVyMaigl1&index=7    , and this is the part that has caused issues for me. I have majorly just copied the code from here but did multiple changes after i realized it was not working. I am not familiar with tilemaps either.

I think your problem with alignment is related to floats like in this line:
Scale of moveplate: x = 1.4375, y = 1.4375
Try playing around with float values and see that you choose fixed numbers, lets say x=4 and y=4 and fix the rest accordingly.

Thanks a lot for going through it but unfortunately that’s not it.
I’ve tried all the float values I could and got the info that the scale of moveplate must match the scale of one cell on the board in Unity.
That being 1.4375 and it still didn’t work :/
